# Is never touching merged code again realistic?

Tags: code-quality

My boss has this idea in his head that once something gets through code review and lands in develop it should be "good enough" to never be touched again.

He is not very pushy, he has been a developer for 10+ years and still codes. So I can't just put it down to "he just doesn't know how programming works". He is not the unaware manager type.

To me it just seems so utterly unrealistic though. You just cannot predict what's going to happen.

An interaction no one foresaw? A new feature request that requires stuff to be changed. Code can also just strictly be not good enough. Not every developer can be an expert in frontend, backend, database stuff, library X we heavily rely on for this project.

It also seems to happen in literally every stage of a project. Early on you tear infrastructure decisions back down because you realize they don't quite hold up anymore, or never did. In the middle you can realize that something just doesn't scale well. In production you have no idea what kind of edge cases end users are going to find.

Comment: Please elaborate. Does your boss literally rejects any later PR which touches the code, or he demands all code quality issues to be resolved before merging, or he wants to implement any textually adjanced, even if not much logically related, functionality in one PR, or what?

Answer (score 4):

If your organization writes software that runs in appliances (e.g. a dishwasher or thermostat), then yes, it is perfectly realistic, because it is necessary. You can't really patch a dishwasher's software after it has shipped, not without enormous expense. So organizations that make software that physically ships do this all the time.

On the other hand, if we are talking about a web site, generally speaking that is simply not how it is done, because it is not cost effective and not a good competitive strategy. Modern software organizations often take the perspective that "perfection is the enemy of good enough" and tend to compromise on quality in favor of time-to-market because it is quite easy to update a web site after it has gone live.

I am not sure what sort of company you work for, but it sounds like your boss has set a high bar for quality. It's his to set. Hopefully he understands the tradeoff and is willing to take the schedule/cost hit in order to reach that bar.

Comment: +1, although there can be a difference between `merged code` and `shipped code`

Comment: Yes. Quite a big difference. Its the difference between "we have to get it right" and "we have to get it right THE FIRST TIME"